# There are something wrong with variable in PHP. the variable can't be added. Why?

Tags: php, variables

There are something wrong with the variable in PHP.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/class.responsive-bbs.php' );

class Responsive_Bbs_Write Extends Responsive_Bbs {
    
    // property init
    protected $post_title           = 'タイトルなし';
    protected $post_time            = '';
    protected $post_name            = '';
    protected $post_contents        = '';
    protected $post_note            = '';
    protected $addr                 = '';
    protected $remote_addr                 = '';
    protected $remote_host                 = '';
    protected $remote_port                 = '';
    protected $http_user_agent                 = '';
    protected $http_referer                 = '';
    protected $http_accept_language                 = '';

    
    // mail-notification addon property
    protected $order_isset          = array();
    protected $order_count          = '0';
    
    
    
    
    // public construct
    public function __construct() {
        
        parent::__construct();
        
    }
    
    
    
    //投稿内容を取得してグローバル変数に保存
    // public post_check
    public function post_check() {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) && $_POST['title'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['title']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            $this->post_title = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        
        $this->post_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && $_POST['name'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['name']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            $this->post_name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['subscribe2'] ) && $_POST['subscribe2'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['subscribe2']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        //  $this->post_name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['subscribe'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        //ここでチェックボックスの内容を取得できる。
        if ( isset( $_POST['subscribe'] ) && $_POST['subscribe'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['subscribe']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            $subscribe=$_POST['subscribe'];
            foreach($subscribe as $subscribe_name){
                error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$subscribe_name."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
                $this->post_contents=$this->post_contents.$subscribe_name;
                }
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$subscribe."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['subscribe']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        //  $this->post_name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['subscribe'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        //書き換えた内容を取得。
        if ( isset( $_POST['input-note'] ) && $_POST['input-note'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['input-note']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            $this->post_note=$_POST['input-note'];
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$post_note."\n","3","./log/debug.log");


        //  $this->post_name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['subscribe'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        
        if ( isset( $_POST['contents'] ) && $_POST['contents'] !== '' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_POST['contents']."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            $this->post_contents = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['contents'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->post_contents = nl2br( $this->post_contents );
            $this->post_contents = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r", "\r\n" ), '', $this->post_contents );
        }
        
        if ( isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$_SERVER."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            foreach($_SERVER as $servername){
                error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$servername."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
                }
            $this->addr = htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            //HTTP変数
            $this->$remote_addr         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_addr ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            $this->$remote_host         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$remote_port         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_user_agent     = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_referer            = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_accept_language    = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_addr ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_host ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_port ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$http_user_agent ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->addr."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        }
    }
    
    // public bbs_write
    public function knowlege_write() {
        
        $post_res  = '0';
        
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['response-number'] ) && $_POST['response-number'] !== '' ) {
            $post_res = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['response-number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        // uniqid関数、ID作成
        $main_data_id = uniqid();
        $ref_data_id = uniqid();

        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO rb_post ( id, title, time, user_id, contents, res, delegate, remote_addr ) VALUES ( :id, :title, :time, :user_id, :contents, :res, 'true', :remote_addr)" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $main_data_id );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':title', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':time', $this->post_time );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':user_id', $this->post_name );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':contents', $this->post_contents );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':res', $post_res );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_addr', $this->addr );
        $stmt->execute();
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( $stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            echo 'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        } else {
            $this->mail_send();
            echo 'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        }
        //自分が書き換えた書き込み
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO rb_post ( id, title, time, user_id, contents, res, delegate, remote_addr ) VALUES ( :id, :title, :time, :user_id, :contents, :res, 'true', :remote_addr)" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $ref_data_id );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':title', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':time', $this->post_time );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':user_id', $this->post_name );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':contents', $this->post_note );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':res', $post_res );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_addr', $this->addr );
        $stmt->execute();
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( $stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            echo 'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        } else {
            $this->mail_send();
            echo 'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        }
        $category_no=0;

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO rb_main ( id, title, time, user_id, reference_id, category, res, remote_addr, remote_host, remote_port, http_user_agent, http_referer, http_accept_language ) VALUES ( :id, :title, :time, :user_id, :reference_id, :category, :res, :remote_addr, :remote_host, :remote_port, :http_user_agent, :http_referer, :http_accept_language)" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $main_data_id );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':title', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':time', $this->post_time );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':user_id', $this->post_name );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':reference_id', NULL );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':category', $category_no );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':res', $post_res );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_addr', $this->$remote_addr );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_host', $this->$remote_host );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_port', $this->$remote_port );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_user_agent', $this->$http_user_agent );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_referer', $this->$http_referer );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_accept_language', $this->$http_accept_language );
        $stmt->execute();
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( $stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url.$stmt->errorInfo()[0]."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            echo 'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        } else {
            $this->mail_send();
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            echo 'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        }
        //自分が書き換えた書き込み
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO rb_main ( id, title, time, user_id, reference_id, category, res, remote_addr, remote_host, remote_port, http_user_agent, http_referer, http_accept_language ) VALUES ( :id, :title, :time, :user_id, :reference_id, :category, :res, :remote_addr, :remote_host, :remote_port, :http_user_agent, :http_referer, :http_accept_language)" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $ref_data_id );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':title', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':time', $this->post_time );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':user_id', $this->post_name );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':reference_id', $main_data_id );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':category', $category_no );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':res', $post_res );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_addr', $this->$remote_addr );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_host', $this->$remote_host );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_port', $this->$remote_port );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_user_agent', $this->$http_user_agent );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_referer', $this->$http_referer );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':http_accept_language', $this->$http_accept_language );
        $stmt->execute();
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( $stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url.$stmt->errorInfo()[0]."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            echo 'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        } else {
            $this->mail_send();
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            echo 'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        }

    }
    
    
    // public bbs_write
    public function bbs_write() {
        
        $post_res  = '0';
        
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['response-number'] ) && $_POST['response-number'] !== '' ) {
            $post_res = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['response-number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        

        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO rb_post ( id, title, time, user_id, contents, res, delegate, remote_addr ) VALUES ( :id, :title, :time, :user_id, :contents, :res, 'true', :remote_addr)" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':title', $this->post_title );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':time', $this->post_time );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':user_id', $this->post_name );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':contents', $this->post_contents );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':res', $post_res );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':remote_addr', $this->addr );
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        $stmt->execute();
        
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

        if ( $stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            echo 'write_failed,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        } else {
            $this->mail_send();
            echo 'write_success,'.$this->post_time.','.$this->url;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public bbs_edit
    public function bbs_edit() {
        

        

            $update_stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "UPDATE rb_post SET title = :title, name = :name, contents = :contents WHERE ( id = :id )" );
        
        
    
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public bbs_delete
    public function bbs_delete() {
        
        $delete_post_id = '';
        
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['delete-number'] ) && $_POST['delete-number'] !== '' ) {
            $delete_post_id = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['delete-number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        
        
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM rb_post WHERE ( id = :id )" );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $delete_post_id );
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ( $row['res'] === '0' ) {
            
            $delete_stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( "DELETE FROM rb_post WHERE ( id = :id )" );
            $delete_stmt->bindParam( ':id', $delete_post_id );
            $delete_stmt->execute();


            
        } else {

            
        }
        
        
        if ( $delete_stmt->errorInfo()[0] !== '00000' ) {
            echo 'delete_failed,'.$this->url;
        } else {
            echo 'delete_success,'.$this->url;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    
    
    
    // public url_check
    public function url_check() {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
    

        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public block_ip
    public function block_ip() {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
        

        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public block_word
    public function block_word() {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
        

        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public mail_send
    public function mail_send() {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
        
        
        if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['responsive_bbs_login'] ) ) {

        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // public approval_change
    public function approval_change( $mode ) {
        error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
        

        
    }
    
}

?>
```

When I tried to use "$post_note" that is grobal variable, even I add the some variable there. It bacame empty!
I checked my code many times but there are no problem.
But other grobal variable can use normaly only "$post_note" has problem.

Additional question.

And when I tried to use

```
    protected $remote_addr                 = '';
    protected $remote_host                 = '';
    protected $remote_port                 = '';
    protected $http_user_agent                 = '';
    protected $http_referer                 = '';
    protected $http_accept_language                 = '';
```

these global variable, everything add same variable.

```
            $this->$remote_addr         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_addr ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");

            $this->$remote_host         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$remote_port         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_user_agent     = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_referer            = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_accept_language    = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_addr ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_host ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$remote_port ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->$http_user_agent ."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
            error_log(__FILE__.'('.__LINE__.')'.$this->addr."\n","3","./log/debug.log");
```

When I see the variable

```
            $this->$remote_addr         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

remote_addr has "::1"

but after go through

```
            $this->$remote_host         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$remote_port         = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_user_agent     = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
            $this->$http_referer            = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

here, it changes "ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"

Why?

I also add logs.

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(106)/Brain/editor1.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(106)/Brain/editor1.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(106)/Brain/editor1.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(106)1640755666.5604
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(106)1640755666
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(111)::1
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(118)ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(119)ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(120)ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Brain/php/class.responsive-bbs-write.php(121)ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Thank you!

Comment: The language you use is hard to follow. You've used the term "global variable" a few times, but in all of those cases the code you provide doesn't show any use of global variables, are you confusing global variables with class members ?

Comment: Use `$this->remote_host` not `$this->$remote_host` as it uses variable name with value that `$remote_host` has.

Comment: But aside from that, the main problem is that you're using syntax like `$this->$remote_addr` which is bad, you ment to use `$this->remote_addr`. Both are valid but they mean VERY different things. You're making the same mistake in many places, so i suggest searching for `->$` and replacing that with `->` to begin with.

Comment: @Raxi Thank you so much! I can solve it! you guys are so kind and amazing! Thank you so much!